# Is there a slot in qml Switch when checked status is changed?

Tags: switch-statement, qml, checked

Just like OnClicked, I'd like to know whether there is a slot for checked changed in a Qml Switch.
When the checked status is changed, the slot is entered.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-switch.html) which will tell you that a `Switch` is based off the `AbstractButton`, using the `checked` property. In the [documentation for AbstractButton](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-abstractbutton.html#toggled-signal) the `toggled` signal is emitted whenever a checkable button is interactively toggled. You can connect a "slot" to this signal with the following code:

```
Switch {
    onToggled: console.log("I was toggled")
}
```